# How to convert a string back into a form to submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, forms

Once the user clicks submit I'm rendering an intermediate page with a thank you / processing message present, one of the props for this page is a stringified form thats held on the BE then eventually passed to this component that I need to submit while this page is showing.

I can see the form data but whenever I try to submit it I keep seeing .submit is not a function, I've tried parsing it, with JSON.parse but since this is a HTML form thats failing, DOMParser converts this successfully back into a HTML form but I'm unsure on how to submit that, I've tried wrapping the stringified form in a new Function then immediately invoking it but no matter what I try this form wont submit.

Normally I'd just submit the form then move to the intermediate page but this is a business requirement so I'm unable to go down that route, instead I've setup a useEffect that will call form.submit() once the page loads.

Let me know if you need further context or have any questions, any assistance would be appreciated.

Heres the code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const ProcessingOrder = ({ form }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    form.submit();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p className="title">Thank you!</p>
      <p className="text">
        We're processing your order now...
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProcessingOrder;
```

Heres the Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: form.submit is not a function
```

Comment: Please add your code and the error message.

Comment: @Ada code and error message added.

Comment: How are you calling `ProcessingOrder()`?

Comment: @mykaf <ProcessingOrder form={form} /> where the passed form is a stringified html form handed to me from the BE

Comment: Are you converting the stringified html back into a valid html form element before you submit it?

Comment: What does your stringified form look like? I think you can only submit a form element, so you need it to refer to the original form, unless you want to send it in a FormData object via AJAX.

Comment: Ada I tried that with DOMParser but the error remains the same, do you know if theres any other way to  convert a string back into a form? mykaf it looks exactly like a standard HTML form but as a string, thats why JSON.Parse fails as it doesnt recognise the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this using dangerouslySetInnerHTML to add the form to a div that I can then render to the page with display hidden to keep it from the user while I submit it.

checkout this article on logrocket I found for more details:
https://blog.logrocket.com/using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-in-a-react-application/

Thanks for helping out.